# How to use modman for managing modules in github?

Tags: modman

I am trying to use `modman` (https://github.com/colinmollenhour/modman) for managing my Extensions in github.

First I am trying to add `MagePsycho_Someext` extension as demo.

So far I have done the following steps

```
/var/www/magento-dir/ -> My Magento Installation Dir
/var/www/MagePsycho_Extensions/ --> Git Repository Dir
```

1. `cd /var/www/MagePsycho_Extensions/`
2. `git clone git@github.com:magepsycho/Someext.git`
3. `touch modman`
4. `git commit -am 'Modman file added'`
5. `git push origin master`
6. `cd /var/www/magento-dir/`
7. `modman init`
8. `modman clone git@github.com:magepsycho/Someext.git`
9. Developed the extension 'MagePsycho_Someext' in /var/www/magento-dir with the following files

   - app/etc/modules/MagePsycho_Someext.xml
   - app/code/local/MagePsycho/Someext/etc/config.xml
   - app/code/local/MagePsycho/Someext/Helper/Data.php

10 Added the files mapping info in /var/www/magento-dir/.modman/Someext/modman as

```
app/etc/modules/MagePsycho_Someext.xml  app/etc/modules/MagePsycho_Someext.xml
app/code/local/MagePsycho/Someext/etc/config.xml app/code/local/MagePsycho/Someext/etc/config.xml
app/code/local/MagePsycho/Someext/Helper/Data.php app/code/local/MagePsycho/Someext/Helper/Data.php
```

11 `modman update Someext`

but got the following errors:

```
WARNING: Target does not exist (.modman/Someext/modman):
 app/etc/modules/MagePsycho_Someext.xml  app/etc/modules/MagePsycho_Someext.xml
```

**Notes**:
I am developing extensions in `/var/www/magento-dir/`. And want to deploy these extensions(one per repository) in github using modman.
When I am finished with module development, I want those files to be added to the repository. For that I have used .modman/*/modman file for mapping. But unable to make it work.

Where and what am I missing?
Or Is this the incorrect approach?

**[EDIT]**

I just realised that my approach is just opposite. First, You have to add extension files and modman with path mappings, push it to the repo and then pull it using `modman clone`.

How would you do if you first develop the extension and then use modman for pushing changes to the repo?

Comment: Can't give a comprehensive reply at the moment but generally you shouldn't be modifying stuff in .modman folder.

This is a good starting point https://github.com/colinmollenhour/modman/wiki/Tutorial

Comment: I am not sure where to manage the mappings. in /var/www/MagePsycho_Extensions/Someext/modman? If yes then have to push the changes to github and pull it using modman update?

Comment: I don't understand why you are referencing the extension directly, if is in a repo you can download it directly from there.

Comment: Inside your extension root repo there should be a modman file with the mappings defined.

Comment: Wait are you trying to pull the extension from /var/www/magento-dir/ into a separate repo ?

Comment: @AllanMacGregor /var/www/magento-dir/ is where I will be developing extensions but since I want to make different repos for different modules, want to link it to another directory using modman. I thought this is what modman is for.

Comment: Just a friendly BUMP!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I figured out the way to manage Magento modules using modman(not the perfect way though but it works for me)

Assumptions

```
/var/www/magento-dir/ -> My Magento Installation Dir
/var/www/MagePsycho_Extensions/ --> Git Repo Dir
```

1. `cd /var/www/MagePsycho_Extensions/`
2. `git clone git@github.com:magepsycho/Someext.git`
3. `touch modman`
4. `git commit -am 'Modman file added'`
5. `git push origin master`
6. `cd /var/www/magento-dir/`
7. `modman init`
8. `modman link /var/www/MagePsycho_Extensions/Someext`
9. Now develop the extension 'MagePsycho_Someext' in /var/www/magento-dir/.modman/Someext with the following files

   - app/etc/modules/MagePsycho_Someext.xml
   - app/code/local/MagePsycho/Someext/etc/config.xml
   - app/code/local/MagePsycho/Someext/Helper/Data.php

10 Add the files mapping info in /var/www/magento-dir/.modman/Someext/modman as

```
app/etc/modules/MagePsycho_Someext.xml  app/etc/modules/MagePsycho_Someext.xml
app/code/local/MagePsycho/Someext/etc/config.xml app/code/local/MagePsycho/Someext/etc/config.xml
app/code/local/MagePsycho/Someext/Helper/Data.php app/code/local/MagePsycho/Someext/Helper/Data.php
```

11 `modman repair`
12 `cd /var/www/magento-dir/.modman/Someext`
13 `git add app/etc/modules/MagePsycho_Someext.xml  app/code/local/MagePsycho/Someext/etc/config.xml app/code/local/MagePsycho/Someext/Helper/Data.php`
14 `git commit -m 'Extension files updated.'`
15 `git push origin master`
16 That's all.

In summary, you will be working on magento-dir/.modman/Someext directory which is symlinked to magento-dir. Whenever you add new files to your extension you have to update the modman file and run `modman repair` which keeps the symlinks up-to date.

If anyone has better approach, please do share.

Answer (score 6):

So my advice here is since you have a local copy of the extension anyway then use the `link` and `deploy` commands rather than the `clone`

In your case you would simply call:

1. `modman init`
2. `modman link ../Your_Extension_Path` (if this is a single extension)
3. `modman deploy Your_Extension_Path`

This method needs you to have the modman file complete in your extension directory with file mappings but from your comments it appears you already have this.

From my understanding the files need to be in the extension dir first, they will then by linked into the magento dir so then when you make future edits to the files under magento the extension files are also changed. Maybe there is a way of creating a modman extension from a magento directory but sadly I do not know it.

A simple way of coping files from Magento to an extension dir is either having two windows explorers open for windows and copy them across or use something like [midnight commander](https://www.midnight-commander.org/)

*Note: I have only used the modman for php version but this process works for that*

Comment: /var/www/MagePsycho_Extensions/ will be have more extensions say: Extension1, Extension2 with different repositories. Will that make a difference using your approach?

Comment: not sure but I guess you would just need two levels to link like `../MagePsycho_extenstion/Extension1` and then deploy would either be `MagePsycho_extenstion/Extension1` or `Extension1` I am not sure without trying it out.

Comment: After following your link & deploy approach, gives the same error
WARNING: Target does not exist (.modman/MagePsycho_Someext/modman):
 app/etc/modules/MagePsycho_Someext.xml  app/etc/modules/MagePsycho_Someext.xml

Comment: @MagePsycho and you actually have this file in your extension?

Comment: Nope. I want to export related files from my Magento dir to Extension dir. I thought file mappings will do that. Isn't that overhead if you copy all the changed/new files to the extension dir from magento dir and deploy? I now guess that the approach I am following is not correct.

Comment: From my understanding the files need to be in the extension dir first, they will then by linked into the magento dir so then when you make future edits to the files under magento the extension files are also changed. Maybe there is a way of creating a modman extension from a magento directory but sadly I do not know it.

Comment: The "deploy" step doesn't seem to do anything extra.  When left out the end result is the same.  "link" must do everything that "deploy" does.